# Calculating appropriate rewards for Uniswap like Liquidity pool contract (Solidity)

Tags: math, solidity

I'm trying to calculate rewards for liquidity providers and I found this equation that Uniswap apparently uses:
`Basic Formula (L = liquidity): (L_you / L_others) * (24h_swap_volume * pool_fee_rate)`
And I'm trying to implement this in my smart contract but I can't seem to be able to because the liquidity held by others will always be larger than the liquidity you hold which requires a decimal value so my question is: How do I use this equation in a Solidity smart contract without falling into floating-point hell?

Comment: See [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity), and [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a little more digging I found that you can use ABDKMath to achieve this you can find more information using the links below:
Library: https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity
Article: https://www.bitcoininsider.org/article/68630/10x-better-fixed-point-math-solidity
As a code example here is a quick snippet of how I implemented this:

```
uint256 fee = ABDKMath64x64.mulu(
        ABDKMath64x64.divu(
          tokensProvided,
          others
        ),
        taxableValue
      );
```

This is probably not the best solution but it worked for me. Also, take a look at https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math for a higher precision fixed-point math library.
Regarding gas efficiency here is a quote from the PRB math lib:

> The typeless PRBMath library is faster than ABDKMath for abs, exp,
> exp2, gm, inv, ln, log2. Conversely, it is slower than ABDKMath for
> avg, div, mul, powu and sqrt. There are two technical reasons why
> PRBMath lags behind ABDKMath's mul and div functions

---

**So for this use case, I think it is a better idea to use ABDK Math instead of PRB math unless you plan on transferring more than 2 to the 128th power of Wei.**

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of:** `(L_you / L_others) * (24h_swap_volume * pool_fee_rate)`

**Use:** `(L_you * 24h_swap_volume * pool_fee_rate)/ L_others`